# Isomorphisms with factor groups

Tags: group-theory

Let H and K be normal subgroups such that H$\vee$K=G and H$\cap{K}$=$\left\{{e}\right\}$, where H$\vee$K=. Prove that G/H$\simeq$K and that G/K$\simeq$H.

I know elements of H$\vee$K should be of the form $m^i$, with $m^i$ an element of H or K. I also know what G/H and G/K represent (the factor groups), but I don't know how to begin this proof.

Any insight? I don't think I understand very well what I have to prove.

Answer (score 0):

In order to show that $\frac{G}{H} \cong K$, we need to find a map $\phi:\frac{G}{H}\to K$ that satisfies

- $\phi(ab) = \phi(a)\phi(b)$ for all $a, b \in \frac{G}{H}$
- $\phi$ is a bijection.

By definition, $\frac{G}{H} = \{gH:g \in G\}$. Hint: Define $\phi$ by $\phi(gH) = g$ where $g$ is an element of the group $G$. Try to show that this satisfies the above 2 properties. A similar map can be used to show that $\frac{G}{K} \cong H$.

Comment: How do you know g$\in$K such that the function is well defined? Aren't the elements of g be elements of K or L but not both? (hence their intersection is just e)